# How do I assign javascript variable to php variable?

Tags: php, javascript

i have a javascript variable which have some value that variable value assign to php variable how i do this thing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var view = true;
var bcount=10;
var wcount=10;
var tcount=10;
</javascript>
<?php
$whitelistcount=????
?>
```

in this code i have no use ajax and jquery only simple javascript and core php

Comment: Most simple and quick solution except submitting hidden form is using jQuery and AJAX. Any reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: You cannot do it just like that. PHP is server side, JavaScript is client side. However, as said, it can be done using AJAX.

Comment: this question was asked over 9000 times!

Answer (score 4):

You could put your value into a hidden input field of a HTML form an submit it to the server, where your PHP can deal with it.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="whatever the hell you want" />`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript can`t comunicate with PHP directly. There are two ways - AJAX or submitting a form populated with JavaScript.

The other way is PHP comunicating with JavaScript - PHP can generate the JavaScript code inside your HTML page.